# Mocking third party API in Play controller

Tags: testing, playframework-2.0, mockito

In an app based on the Play! Framework (2.0, Java) I want to mock a third party API when testing the controllers. I've picked Mockito for this because I couldn't find out about any built-in mocking features in Play!

I have something like this:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
  ThirdParty thirdParty = mock(ThirdParty.class);
  when(thirdParty.someUnwantedMethod()).thenReturn("foo");

  running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.MyController.doImportantStuff());
      verify(thirdParty.someUnwantedMethod()); // Verify that method in mock/API is called
      assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("foo");
    }
  });
}
```

(the controller in turn calls "someUnwantedMethod()" on an instance of the ThirdParty class which should use the mock instead when testing)

How do I get my controller to pick up the mock?

Comment: I don't know Play, however as a friendly remark : **you should not mock types you don't own**, there's many reasons for that statement, although I found the arguments explained in Growing Object Oriented Software book to be the best. Hope that helps (in the long run) Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Introduce a static setThirdParty method in MyController
2. In your test, before "callAction", call MyController.setThirdParty(thirdParty)

There is nothing play-specific about this

Comment: I guess this is the way to go but is it The Right Way?